# Want to resolve a dictionary whose key is a field in a model

Tags: django, django-templates

I have

```
{% for competency in domain.competency_set.all %}
<td> {{competency.id}} {{scoredict.8}}  {% with cid=competency.id %} {{ scoredict.cid }} {% endwith %} </td>
```

so scoredict.8 displays a value but when competency.id is 8, scoredict.cid comes up empty.  What am I doing wrong? What's the workaround?

I can see why scoredict.competency.id doesn't work, but I don't see how to change the order of evaluation. If I could force order of evaluation with parentheses I'd want something like scoredict.(competency.id)

Comment: Basically, django templates deliberately don't do that (unless the world has changed since I last looked at it). Typically you'd try to find a design that doesn't require it, probably by preprocessing in your view, or write a custom tag or filter.

Comment: Thanks. To be specific added 

from django import template  

register = template.Library()  

@register.filter  
def get_item(dictionary, key):  
... return dictionary.get(key,"")  

to <app_dir>/templatetags/<app_name>_extras and put 

`{% load <app_name>_extras %}` in the template.

Then 

`{{ scoredict|get_item:competency.id }}`

did the trick. Thanks!